# What is the cost of playing a youtube video, via the android youtube player? (in quota terms)

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-youtube-api, quota

I have an app, which gets the videoId by other means, and needs to use the Android youtube player, to play the video.

My question is, whether the playing of the video costs any credit, in the quota which is allowed by the API, when I create an API Key.

I know that the method which is called is

```
loadVideo(videoId)
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)

And I've also tried to estimate what the cost would be, by exploring this quota calculator
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

But I don't know, and cannot seem to find what methods/type of calls does playing a video use, so I can see the cost in this quota explorer.

Can someone help / direct me into where I can find what is the cost of playing a single video, if I already have the videoId?

This needs to be done for a production app, for which I have to provide a document where it has it in writing, what the cost is, so we can decide on a solution.

Comment: Someone may correct me but I don't think there is a quota on actual plays - certainly I can;t see one on the calculator. I would think it is in YouTube's interest to have people watch the videos, so possibly this is the driver.